# Поиск локальных экстремумов

Tags: python, оптимизация, numpy, анализ-данных, scipy

Есть датафрейм, в нем значения, где для каждой интервала от положительных данных до отрицательных и обратно, нужно найти экстремум и записать результат.
Пример:

```
[0.0828,0.0872, 0.08, 0.0658, 0.054, 0.0482, 0.039, 0.031, 0.0242, 0.019, 
 0.0242, 0.0152, 0.0182, 0.0178, 0.022, 0.0232, 0.0282, 0.0342, 0.0272, 
 0.0302, 0.0236, 0.0176, 0.0124, 0.0136, 0.0054, -0.002, -0.0104, -0.017, 
 -0.0104, -0.017, -0.0176, 0.0428, 0.0472, 0.04, 0.0358, 0.034, 0.0282, 0.049, 
 0.021, 0.0342, 0.039, 0.0242, 0.0252]
```

- здесь экстремумы будут 0.0872 и -0.0176 и 0.049

Есть код, но он ничего не отображает:

```
from pandas import read_csv 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

df = pd.read_csv('E:\df_dif.csv')

data = np.array(df_dif['dif'])
print(argrelextrema(data, np.greater_equal,order=1))

>> (array([    50,     59,     61, ..., 456059, 456072, 456138], dtype=int32),)
```

Тоесть печатается индес, но и изменение индекса не помогает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция [`argrelextrema(data, comparator, axis=0, order=1, mode='clip')`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html) возвращает индексы точек нижних или верхних экстремумов, в зависимости от указанной функции сравнения `comparator=<...>`.

Можно отдельно получить индексы нижних экстремумов и индексы верхних экстремумов, объединить их и остортировать по возрастанию (т.к. это *индексы* исходных значений). И наконец, выбрать по полученным индексам все экстремумы.

Пример:

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

In [33]: data = np.array([0.23,0.29,0.35,0.14,-0.05,-0.18,-0.13,-0.06,0.12,0.49,0.20])

In [34]: idx_minimas = argrelextrema(data, np.less)[0]

In [35]: idx_maximas = argrelextrema(data, np.greater)[0]

In [36]: idx = np.sort(np.concatenate((idx_minimas, idx_maximas)))

In [37]: idx
Out[37]: array([2, 5, 9], dtype=int64)

In [38]: data[idx]
Out[38]: array([ 0.35, -0.18,  0.49])
```

---

чтобы найти *глобальные* экстремумы достачно найти минимум и максимум из всех экстремумов:

```
In [10]: data[idx].max()
Out[10]: 0.49

In [11]: data[idx].min()
Out[11]: -0.18
```