# Анализ локальных екстремумов графика по входному масиву

Tags: алгоритм, графики

есть масив даных который содержит в себе точки графика, индекс елемента это ось X, значение елемента это ось Y, надо найти локальные екстремумы, есть ли готовые программные реализации?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [связанный вопрос...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1033195/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Собственно, точки, у которых слева и справа точки с одновременно меньшим/большим значением?

Comment: Во-первых, надо точнее определиться с тем, что в рамках данной задачи следует понимать под локальным экстремумом. Насколько локальным? Почему, например, на вашем графике есть небольшие пики и впадины, которые вы не считаете локальным экстремумом?

Comment: @Harry, а как быть тогда с 1 0 0 0 0 2 - где тут именно локальный минимум :)

Comment: @Harry рисунок подправил, дело в том что надо более общая картина, и если брать во внимание каждую выделющуюся точку из графика между двух других, то будет слишком много екстремумов, и не удастса оценить общуюю картину(не подходит под задание), надо брать +- глобальную картину.

Comment: @Harry , 1 0 0 0 0 2, такого там точно не будет во входных даных минимум 1000 елементов и все разные, разные в плане что подряд одинаковых не будет идти

Comment: @Harry  есть ньюанс что может быть к примеру вот  так:
елементов 100 не важно каких в даном примере потом (падающая последовательность елементов 20) потом  идут числа 37 25 23 24 23 25 28 потом  (возрастающая елементов 20), и в даном примере как бы можно взять два екстремума по 23 но на общей картине это  не целесообразно и таких моментов может быть много
и даже в падающий момент графика числа могут идти не в порядке спадания строго один за одним а как бы зубчасто с падающей тенденцией

Comment: @Xander а вот локальность экстремума надо определять динамически в зависимости например от количсества елеменотов что бы была +- глобальная картина графика

Comment: Тогда это уже не задача поиска локальных экстремумов, а задача аппроксимации/интерполяции. Собственно, я к этому и вел - уточнению, что же нужно *на самом деле*...

Comment: @Harry, ну в результате всёравно надо будет найти екстремумы, а аппроксимация в даном случае будет частью алгоритма)

Comment: В таком случае мне видится такое решение, чтоб не частить с экстремумами, ведь задача не стоит достичь их определенного количества, сначала аппроксимация/интерполяция(сглаживание до заданного количества соседних точек графика) а уже после в полученом графике ищем экстремумы отмечая их на исходном графике, это и будут экстремумы с заданной заранее локальностью(точностью). осталось выбрать вариант предварительного линейного сглаживания: по скольким точкам или линейная регрессия, как варианты